# Kotlin continuing to else clause after return

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to figure out how returns work in Kotlin. Right now I have a function that with two nested for loops.

All returns should return for the parent function getValue(), one seems to work as expected, the other one does does not.

```
val myArray = arrayOf(
    MyObj("String 1", mapOf(Pair(MyEnum.apple, "String 2"))),
    MyObj("String 2", mapOf(Pair(MyEnum.orange, "String 1"),
            Pair(MyEnum.apple, "String 3"))),
    MyObj("String 3", mapOf(Pair(MyEnum.orange, "String 2")))
)

val myObj = myArray[1]

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    getValue(MyEnum.apple)
}

fun getValue(myEnum: MyEnum) {
    myObj.myMap.forEach { (enum, str) ->
        if (enum == myEnum) {
            myArray.forEach {obj ->
                if (obj.name == str) {
                    if (checkStuff(obj)) {
                        println("checkStuff returned true")
                        return // this continues to printLn
                    }
                    println("returned false")
                    return // This appears to return as expected
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Should not be hit")
        }
    }
}

fun checkStuff(obj: MyObj): Boolean {
    return obj.name == "String 1"
}

data class MyObj (val name: String, val myMap: Map<MyEnum, String>)

enum class MyEnum {
    apple, orange, pear
}
```

The return inside the checkStuff if always continues onto the printLn.

From reading through documentation, I thought that adding return@getValue would return for the top level function and exit out of that function.

I seem to be missing something. How would I make the first return not continue on to the else clause with the printLn?

Comment: The code wouldn't compile. To discuss about how and why some code bahaves the wy it does, we need something that actually compiles and runs. Post a complete minimal example that compiles, runs, and reproduces your issue.

Comment: I have edited my question to include some code that will compile and reproduce the behavior I am getting. Thanks.

Comment: All these `return` statements will return from the entire `getValue` function when they are hit. As for "The return inside the checkStuff if always continues onto the println.", this happens because `checkStuff` is only called once with the third element of your array, and it evaluates to `false` on that element. This is not a language but a logic issue, I suggest stepping through your code with the debugger and seeing what values your various `if` checks operate on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your *if-statements* logic,
at current state `checkStuff` can't return `true`

```
fun getValue(myEnum: MyEnum) {
    myObj.myMap.forEach { (enum, str) ->
        if (enum == myEnum) { // Pair(MyEnum.APPLE, "String 3")
            myArray.forEach { obj -> // str = "String 3"
                if (obj.name == str) { // obj.name = "String 3"
                    if (checkStuff(obj)) {  // "String 3" == "String 1"
                                            // checkStuff: obj.name == "String 1"
                        ...
                    }
                    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statements work fine. The problem with your code is that the only time `checkStuff(obj)` gets called it returns false, therefore the following is never called:

```
`println("checkStuff returned true")
 return // this continues to printLn`
```

If you make the appropriate changes to `fun checkStuff(..) {...}` you will find that the code works just like you expected.